# How can I display this pdf correctly in firefox?

Tags: browser

I am trying to open https://www.sec.gov/info/edgar/specifications/edgarfm-vol2-v60.pdf.

My OS and firefox info:

```
$ uname -a
Linux debian 5.10.0-20-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 5.10.158-2 (2022-12-13) x86_64 GNU/Linux
firefox -version
Mozilla Firefox 109.0.1
```

Shown in firefox
[image: shown in firefox]

Shown in chrome
[image: Shown in chrome]

Shown in edge
[image: Shown in edge]

Shown in opera
[image: Shown in opera]

The same pdf file is opened correctly without any special settings by all browsers except firefox.How can I display this pdf correctly in firefox?

Comment: Can't reproduce with Debian Bullseye and FFox 102.7.0esr (64-bit): [screenshot](https://imgur.com/a/I3j8LLO). Maybe you could add your OS and FFox versions?  [Mozilla's github](https://github.com/mozilla/pdf.js/issues/14147) has a posting about blurry PDF, maybe that helps you forward.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firefox (PDF.js to be precise) has troubles substituting fonts - it's a well known every old bug. Please use Chrome or Adobe Reader under Wine.